# Keeping aspect ratio of image but cropping when hitting max/min height

Tags: css, image, responsive-design

I'm trying to make this image responsive that it will resize and keep it aspect ratio at all sizes. However above 650px, its height won't increase but will just crop the top and bottom to keep the ratio and not stretch. Also I want the image height won't go below 200px and just the left and right. I want image to always be center too. Here is what I have so far: https://jsfiddle.net/4q83mh41/

```
<div class="hero">
<img src="http://wpdevserver.x10host.com/wp-content/themes/wp/img/hero1.jpg">
</div>


.hero {
    width: 100%;
    min-height:200px;
    max-height: 650px;
    position: relative;
}
.hero img {
    width: 100%;
    height:auto;
    min-height:200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-height: 650px;
    position:aboslute;
}
```

Many thanks

Comment: I can't think of an easy way to do that in CSS.  If you are willing to use some JS, I can probably whip up a solution involving background images and JS to set the height of the `.hero` element.

Comment: I really want to avoid using background image, but I don't mind using js.

Answer (score 2):

By adding some javascript, the position of the image can be adjusted dynamically inside the `.hero` div.  Additionally, CSS media queries can be used to keep the width of the image correct.

```
.hero {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 650px;
}

.hero img {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  width: auto;
}

@media (min-width:420px) {
  .hero img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }
}
```

The javascript simply listens for resize events and adjusts the `top` and `right` properties of the relatively positioned image to keep it centered. Note that I'm using JQuery to manipulate the properties.

```
var heroresize = function() {
  var aspect = 1800./858,
      maxheight = 650,
      minheight = 200,
      width = $(".hero").width();
  if(width < minheight*aspect) {
    $(".hero img").css("right",(minheight*aspect - width)/2 + "px");
  } else {
    $(".hero img").css("right","0px");
  }

  if(width > maxheight*aspect) {
    $(".hero img").css("top",(maxheight - width/aspect)/2 + "px");
  } else {
    $(".hero img").css("top","0px");
  }
}
$(function(){
  heroresize();
  // remove if you don't need dynamic resizing
  $(".hero").on("resize",heroresize);
});
```

The Javascript may cause some lag/stutter because resize events can be performance-intensive.  If you don't need to worry about dynamic resizes, you can remove the indicated line.

I created a codepen you can play with here: http://codepen.io/regdoug/pen/azxVwd  Note that the codepen has a max height of 350px because that allows you to see the effect without so much resizing.